# Data Analytics with Excecl

Tags: excel-formula

Can anyone help me with the answer to the below attachment?

Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip5To.png)

Comment: Please describe your problem, your desired output and what you've tried, so people with the same problem can make use of the answers that will follow.

Comment: Look into `INDEX` combined with `MATCH` for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: in the sell to the right of the Emp. number in yellow, you have a match function: =Match(MATCH(J4,$D$4:$D$23,0) this will return a number that should equal the S.R. Number in the far Left column of your table.

Based on the SR number, you perform a VLOOKUP for the remaining three metrics. Since the columns in the table can not be altered, I also presume that the table must remain sorted by the SR Number. If that is the case this should help.

=VLOOKUP($K$4,$A$4:$G$23,2,TRUE)
This would return the names.

If this table is being presented to people, and you don't want them to see a random number in the Cell next to the employee code, the you can either hide the column, or you can change the text to white.

Below is what the final would look like. (I just entered the data to represent something close to what you were working with)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjHsn.png)